# Infer type of array items under object key

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference

I have a `Datum<T>` type where `T` may be either a `number` or a `string`. `Datum`s are collected as arrays in an object. I have an `aggregateDatums` function that takes object, key name with `Datum`s array, and returns a datum as well.

```js
export interface Datum<T extends string | number> {
    key: T;
    count: number;
}

const aggregateDatums = <
    TKey extends string | number,
    T extends { [k in K]: Datum<TKey>[] },
    K extends keyof T
    >(data: T, key: K): Datum<TKey>[] => {
    return [];
};

const data = {
    numeric: [{key: 1, count: 1}, {key: 2, count: 2}],
    text: [{key: 'a', count: 1}, {key: 'b', count: 2}],
};

const aggregated = {
    numeric: aggregateDatums(data, 'numeric'), // should be type Datum<number>[], but is Datum<string | number>[]
    text: aggregateDatums(data, 'text'), // should be type Datum<string>[], but is Datum<string | number>[]
};
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgEUxgFcBbAHgBU5RUkATAZzkZimQHM4AfOJMgEZoAfHADeAKDjS4Aa2ABPAFxxKAbikzsEYihX9SQqBoC%20EidqSs4mDhyjAORYIRKlmAXjhUA0opogdEwsbJw8fIJoADSa0tS0wAzMYnAA2rKISHA%20ALoqrmS%20isKpOXAmMTLZAUHM8goQ6KrCABT0RJgqlFFyiio%20AJT5RIWUfgolZR6iklUOJFBZpaYaFhBW8O0wmHBeszIGaAjYKqli9SoAjD3aujBXFeIXcABMNzp6ryY5lTKogadzn04AByTAg953B49IHKUECCFwW6fF7fGImVaWay2eyOZz0XbiWIRUhHE42OwOJyoAruNodHogw7sbAggY9AD0HJYAAsdAAbAlCOAwBRgPC08gGIyTYn-e4U3HUlwjOlbTCM%20Vszncxh84iCuDC0Xigiq8isdhIDiyjESIA)

Because I pass an object and a key that holds array, not an array of `Datum`s directly, the result is typed `Datum<string | number>[]`. My goal is the type to correspond to the type of `Datum`s in source array, so `Datum<string>[]` or `Datum<number>[]`. Any tips on how can I achieve this?

---

The example is simplified to show the problem only. But if I overengineered typings that can be done simpler, please let me know.

Also, I would be grateful if someone can recommend resources on advanced typings in TypeScript. Unfortunately, most resources is about types like `Partial<T>` etc, while I know you can do advanced magic with types :-)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const aggregateDatums = <
    T extends { [k in K]: Datum<string | number>[] },
    K extends keyof T
    >(data: T, key: K): T[K] extends Datum<infer P>[] ? Datum<P>[] : never => {
    throw 'implemented';
};
```

Comment: Please write at least few words what you have changed)

Comment: The type itself works, but it throws error for any return value, even if it's as simple as `return []` or `return data[key]`.

Comment: It depends on how your implementation will be and what you want to achieve. I would make it return merely `T[K]` for example.